Why 22_04-lts-gen2 Azure marketplace image not updated lately?
I have an image build pipeline, using the latest Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy:22_04-lts-gen2 image.
The build hangs on apt-get upgrade as it appears there is a kernel upgrade prompt.
Looking at the image publish history, the most recent image was over 2 months ago, which isn't the normal every ~3 weeks.
202410020
I'm curious why a new image hasn't been published lately, which may get me past this prompt.
"The currently running kernel version is 6.5.0-1025-azure which is not the expected kernel version 6.8.0-1018-azure."

These is not an official Ubuntu image. Please contact whoever maintains it (Azure == Microsoft?) to update it.

My understanding by this page, Ubuntu publishes them.  I could totally be wrong.
https://documentation.ubuntu.com/azure/en/latest/azure-how-to/instances/find-ubuntu-images/#ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish

I see. I was wrong. Please also ask a question on discourse https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/public-cloud/azure/178

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/22-04-lts-gen2-azure-marketplace-image-not-updated-lately/51166
